# nodejs singelton for database connection with sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm just being curious. What is the proper way to open a database connection in nodejs with requires and dependency injection?

In php I would have created a connection once as a singleton in an global variable. However this seems not to be best practice in node. Thus I had the following questions:

1. Where would you open a db connection in node?
2. Would you open the db connection once or multiple times?
3. How can I open the db connection only once while keeping es6 module imports?
4. How can I open multiple db connections through es6 module loading?
5. If I import the same database multiple times, does it result in multiple connections?
6. I rather know and like to control how many connections are opend by my server. E.g. if I write a backend worker with low db access I rather only open one db connection there as running an express server I'd like to open a connection per request. How can I achieve this?

I do know there are similar questions however the not fully seem to answer my question:

- [Singlton in Node ES6](https://derickbailey.com/2016/03/09/creating-a-true-singleton-in-node-js-with-es6-symbols/)
- [Where to connect to the database in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466303/nodejs-where-to-connect-to-the-database-in-code)
- [NodeJS Express Dependency Injection and Database Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989483/nodejs-express-dependency-injection-and-database-connections)

So my basic idea is:

```
/* DbService.js */
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.export = new Sequelize('database', 'username')
```

same with models / instances

```
/* Foo.js */
var db = require("DbService.js");
export var Foo = db.define('foo', {...});
```

And in the code I than load the db / model by

```
/* server.js */

import Foo from './Foo';
Foo.findById('123').then(function(foo) {
    ...
};

var db = require("DbService.js");    
db.query("SELECT * FROM `test`");
```

However in my mind this allways opens a seperate db connection and this feels wrong. So how would you do this probably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually when the app gets loaded, but not necessarily - for eg. you might need to check for authentication against the stored credentials on DB.
2. Since you tagged sequelizejs, you're not creating individual connection when creating `new Sequelize` instance, rather you create connection pool. If you don't specify configs for pooling sequelize will create with [max 1 connection by default](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js#L31).
3. By creating an instance of sequelize (`new Sequelize()`) you're just initializing the connection pool. The actual connection will be created and kept in pool when an actual needs comes up like performing a query.
4. You can create a connection pool which can handle multiple connections by passing appropriate pool config option.
5. Assuming by database you mean `Sequelize` instance, because of the nature of nodejs's module caching you'll always end up in same instance therefore same connection pool.
6. Connection per request is a bad idea in general, since making a connection is relatively a resource consuming operation. Instead make use of connection pool. Since you use Sequelize, it saves your time already.

NOTE - ES6 Modules not implemented yet in nodejs.

Comment: Ok and if not Sequalize ... how can I implement something like this myself?

Comment: @Manuel you can use [`createPool`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) of node-mysql module.

Comment: I thought of a own service like an rest api, cacheing or background tasks api